# Moving Wordpress to another domain with different permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to move Wordpress to another domain and also change the permalinks. So basically what I want is to move from: oldsite.com/PostId-PostName.html to newsite.com/PostName/

I know this can be done from .htaccess, but I don't manage to get it right. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. Also please provide an example URL (from => to) -- I see that you have `oldsite.com/PostId-PostName.html`, but can you be a little bit specific as it can make a difference (for example: `oldsite.com/12345-very-interesting-post.html`)

Comment: Sorry for not being very specific. I want to move from oldsite.com/12345-very-interesting-post.html to newsite.com/very-interesting-post/

Comment: I managed to do this, but it doesn't remove the trailing .html RedirectMatch 301 ([0-9]+).(.*) http://newsite.com/$2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done using Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/):

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
# redirect posts to new site
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-([^/]+)\.html http://www.newsite.com/$2/ [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

This will ONLY redirect URLs like `oldsite.com/12345-very-interesting-post.html`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Codex article dedicated to this: [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't provide any help for what I'm trying to do